# How to match strings to objects?

Tags: c++, object

I am fairly new to C++ (In VS2019), and am trying to make a simple console program. It asks for a bean name, then rates it with a rand() function. My friend said I should use groups and objects to add some ratings of my own into the mix. I now have a group with a few example beans as objects and have ran into an issue. I do not know how to check if the string for the bean name matches the name of any of the objects. (Say if been == pinto, match it with the object Pinto in the DataBean group and use the object's data.) I also do not want to use a string of if statements, as that is messy and unnecessary.
I have not tried much at all, as I'm scared of messing up the program. I asked Google too, but it did not seem to be helpful; I most likely don't have the right keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `std::map<std::string, bean> beans` to perform object lookup at runtime.

It appears to me that you need to learn about [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) at the very least.

The usage would go something like:

```
string name;
cin >> name;

beans[name] = <your bean>;
```

Then later on, you can lookup for beans like

```
string name;
cin >> name;

if (beans.find(name) != beans.end())
{
    beans[name].<do something here>;
}
```

Comment: One more question, does the group have to be in the .cpp file? VS prompted me to put it in its own .h file, so I dont know if that will interfere

Comment: Stupid me, forgot to include it

Comment: `if (beans.find(name) != beans.end()) { beans[name]... }` performs a 2nd redundant lookup. To avoid that, use the `iterator` that `find()` returns, eg: `auto iter = beans.find(name); if (iter != beans.end()) { iter->second...; }`

Comment: Remy, I assume you are using "beans" as the group name, and "bean" as the string?